# Conflito banco sqlite ao realizar o merge no git

Tags: python, django, git, sqlite

Estou trabalhando com outra pessoa num projeto Django e ela é dona do repositório principal. Eu tenho um fork desse repositório e quero atualizá-lo com o original.

Criei o upstream: `git remote add upstream <endereço-do-repositorio.git>`
Depois: `git fetch upstream`
Até aí correu bem, mas na hora de mergear (`git merge upstream/maste`r) apresentou o erro:

```
warning: Cannot merge binary files: db.sqlite3 (HEAD vs. upstream/master)
Unlink of file 'db.sqlite3' failed. Should I try again? (y/n) n
error: failed to create path 'db.sqlite3': perhaps a D/F conflict?
Auto-merging db.sqlite3
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in db.sqlite3
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

Eu entendi que o problema são as divergências do meu banco com o da outra pessoa, mas como podemos resolver pra conseguir trabalhar em equipe sem causar interferências no projeto principal? Obrigada.

Comment: O banco de dados precisa ser versionado com o Git?

Comment: Você tem que adicinonar a extensão .sqlite3 o arquivo gitignore, não se deve subir banco de dados para o git

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O **Git** está tentando fazer o versionamento do arquivo de banco de dados, um binário, e então gerando um conflito que ele não consegue resolver de forma fácil (e muito menos segura) e por este, e outros motivos, não deve ser versionado no projeto. E no caso do **Django** o histórico de alterações do banco de dados já será armazenado com os arquivos `models.py` como também nas `migrations`.

Solução para o seu problema, remover o `db.sqlite3` do repositório

```
git rm --cached db.sqlite3
```

O `--cached` diz para o **Git** só remover do sistema de versionamento e não apagar o arquivo propriamente dito.

Também é recomendável acrescentar o arquivo no `.gitignore`:

```
echo 'db.sqlite3' >> .gitignore
```

Para que ninguém o coloque de volta no projeto e, daí, enviar as alterações:

```
git add .gitignore
git commit -m "Remove o 'db.slite3' do repositório"
```

E aqui há uma recomendação, o pessoal precisará renomear o `db.sqlite3` antes de atualizar ou receberão algo como a mensagem:

```
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
    db.sqlite3
Please move or remove them before you switch branches.
```

Mas aí é renomear o arquivo, atualizar o repositório e voltar o nome para `db.sqlite3`.

E havendo a necessidade de fazer um *backup* dos dados do **Django** dê uma olhada nos comandos "dumpdata" e "loaddata" do `manage.py`.